# How to submit data with Jersey client POST method

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I am new to Jersey. I need to implement a Jersey client to submit data with POST method.
The curl command is:

```
curl -d '{"switch": "00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01", "name":"flow-mod-1", "priority":"32768", "ingress-port":"1","active":"true", "actions":"output=2"}' http://localhost:8080/wm/staticflowentrypusher/json
```

So I am trying to figure out how to use Jersey client to implement the above curl command.

So far I have done:

```
public class FLClient {

private static Client client;
private static WebResource webResource;
private static String baseuri = "http://localhost:8080/wm/staticflowentrypusher/json";
private static ClientResponse response;
private static String output = null;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {

        client = Client.create();

        webResource = client.resource(baseuri);

                    // implement POST data 

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

Can someone help me with it?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Now I figure it out. Here is my solution:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        Client client = Client.create();

        WebResource webResource = client.resource(baseuri);

        String input = "{\"switch\": \"00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01\", "
                + "\"name\":\"flow-mod-1\", \"priority\":\"32768\", "
                + "\"ingress-port\":\"1\",\"active\":\"true\", "
                + "\"actions\":\"output=2\"}";

        // POST method
        ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("application/json")
                .type("application/json").post(ClientResponse.class, input);

        // check response status code
        if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                    + response.getStatus());
        }

        // display response
        String output = response.getEntity(String.class);
        System.out.println("Output from Server .... ");
        System.out.println(output + "\n");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 22):

If you want to post within a JSON body, here is a better approach.

```
ClientConfig clientConfig = new DefaultClientConfig();              
clientConfig.getFeatures().put(JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING, Boolean.TRUE);     
client = Client.create(clientConfig);

WebResource webResource = client.resource(baseuri);

Map<String,Object> postBody = new HashMap<String,Object>();
//put switch, name,priority....
ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("application/json")
                .type("application/json").post(ClientResponse.class, postBody);
```

Remember you have to include `jersey-json`

Comment: I love this JSON-less json post method.  HashMap.  Neat.

Comment: this sounds cool, but I can't get it to work with FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING and jersey-json.jar:
ClientHandlerException: A message body writer for Java type, class java.util.HashMap, and MIME media type, application/json, was not found - what am I missing?

Answer (score 11):

For future users, with the new version of `jersey` things has changed, so the way of doing such POST method is:

- For versions `1.x` ([@Li'](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1388157/li) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16291306/2069380)) :

  ```
  WebResource webResource = client.resource(baseuri);

  String input = "...";

  ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("application/json")
          .type("application/json").post(ClientResponse.class, input);
  ```
- For versions `2.x`:

  ```
  WebTarget webTarget = client.target(baseuri);

  String input = "...";

  Response response = webTarget.request("application/json").post(Entity.json(input));
  ```

Based on the [Migration Guide](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/migration.html#mig-client-api)

Comment: I don't think (WebTarget).accept() is a part of 2.x, at least not anymore.

Comment: Also, I think for 2.x it should be Response, not ClientResponse.

Comment: @Erhannis you're right on both, I fixed the answer. Thanks